# PropTypes and React Context API syntax error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks, react-context

I have been playing with React Context API but not sure how I am supposed to type-check using the `PropTypes` package, given the `value` is passed down to the child component (Module1) via `useContext()` rather than via traditional props.

I have tried to implement `PropTypes` in both the parent (App) and child (module1) components but it is returning an error. Thanks.

```
import './App.css';
import Module1 from './Module1.js';
import PropTypes  from 'prop-types';



export const MyContext = React.createContext();


const App = () => {

  const [age, setAge] = useState(22);

  const increaseAge = () => {
    return setAge( age -1)
  };
    return (

      <MyContext.Provider value={
        {
          age: age,
          increaseAge: increaseAge
        }
      }>
          <Module1/>
      </MyContext.Provider>

    );


}

App.PropTypes ={ 
  age: PropTypes.number
}

export default App;

==========================================================================================


import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import {MyContext} from './App.js'
import PropTypes  from 'prop-types';


const Module1 = () => {

  const myAge = useContext(MyContext);

    return (
              <div> 
                Your age is: {myAge.age}
                <button onClick={myAge.increaseAge}> increase age </button>
              </div>
          )
}


Module1.PropTypes = {
     MyAge: PropTypes.object
}

export default Module1;
```

Comment: The casing is incorrect. The first "p"  on the assignment to the component needs to be lowercase. Change the assignments to `App.propTypes = {` and `Module1.propTypes = {`.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/12658

Comment: I corrected the casing and it is now rendering. However, propTypes is still not working. I tested it by changing the value of 'age' (22) to a string, but the console is not prompting any warning.